# Email plugin Gradle or Grails?

Tags: grails, gradle

I need to create a project which will have email templates(html) to send emails to users. I am confused how should I create it because I need to use it as Jar in other project so that emails can be sent when something happens. I created a project in `Grails` but I am not sure if I can use this in other non-grails project. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://grails.org/plugin/mail plugin. You can copy this jar file from your project and put in into another.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would create a separate java library (jar file) which is responsible for formating the mails and setting the meta data. Something like a builder pattern:

```
MyMail mail = MyMailer.createMail()
                      .from("sender@foo.com")
                      .to("receiver@bar.com")
                      .subject("Important Stuff")
                      .body(renderVelocityTemplate("mail.html", model))
                      .build()
```

This mail reference can then be passed to the grails mail plugin using an [adapter class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

After that you build an adapter class for your other projects/technologies.